# Ruby Named Capture

Tags: regex, ruby

I have these fields in plain text file.

```
Style 130690 113
Price $335.00
Stock # 932811
```

How can I save the style number, price, and stock # in separate variables using regex and name capturing?

I have tried this, but it did not work.

```
fields = params[:plain].match(/"Price $"(?<price>)/)
```

Comment: Show what you have tried, and add more details, context please.

Comment: I just updated my post with what I tried

Comment: If you put quotes inside the regex, it's going to match literal quotes. So it's looking for the string `"Price $"` (with quotes).

Comment: That's not a correct regex, try search using keyword `regex` and learn something about it.

Comment: Silvio, if I were to take out the quotes, this should work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
style, price, stock = <<~_.scan(/^(?:Style |Price \$|Stock \# )(.+)/).flatten
Style 130690 113
Price $335.00
Stock # 932811
_
# => "130690 113", "335.00", "932811"
```

Comment: Would it be possible for the 113 in the style to not be cut off?

Comment: There are \r at the end of the name captured variables. Is there a way to get rid of those?

Comment: @Shurick You can apply `chomp` to it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the order of the attributes of "style", "price" and "stock" and their associated values is not known. One may then initialise variables `style`, `price` and `stock` as follows.

```
str =<<END
Price $335.00
Style 130690 113
Stock # 932811
END
  #=> "Price $335.00\nStyle 130690 113\nStock # 932811\n"

style_r = /\bstyle +(?=(\d+))/i
str.match(style_r)
style = $1.to_i
  #=> 130690

price_r = /\bprice +\$(?=(\d+\.\d{2}))/i
str.match(price_r)
price = $1.to_f
  #=> 335.0

stock_r = /\bstock +# +(?=(\d+))/i
str.match(stock_r)
stock = $1.to_i
  #=> 932811
```

The regular expression for `style`, `style_r` can be written in "free spacing" mode, which makes it self-documenting:

```
/
\b       # match a word break
style    # match string
[ ]+     # match one or more spaces
(?=      # begin a positive lookahead
  (\d+)  # match one or more digits in capture group 1
)        # end the positive lookahead
/ix      # case-indifferent (i) and free-spacing modes
```

After the match on this regular expression the global variable `$1` is assigned the value of capture group 1.

In free-spacing mode spaces are removed. One way of protecting them is to enclose them in a character class (`[ ]`), which is what I have done. The interpretation of `price_r` and `stock_r` is similar.

Initialising variables in this way is not normally done. It generally would be more useful to create a hash with keys `:style`, `:stock` and `:price`:

```
h = {}

str.match(style_r)
h[:style] = $1.to_i

str.match(price_r)
h[:price] = $1.to_f

str.match(stock_r)
h[:stock] = $1.to_i

h #=> {:style=>130690, :price=>335.0, :stock=>932811}
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition of the question is that this is the content of the text file. Therefore, you can try like this.

```
ary = File.readlines(path_to_your_file, chomp: true)
style, price, stock = ary[0].sub(/Style /, ''), ary[1].sub(/Price \$/, ''), ary[2].sub(/Stock # /, '')
#=> "130690 113", "335.00", "932811"
```